# How to make a custom ModelBinder automatically apply to all properties of a certain type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, custom-model-binder

EDIT: So it turns out that my `ModelBinder` isn't actually the problem. The issue is with my `ValueConverter`. Leaving this here, as I think it illustrates how to do a custom model binder though.

---

There is a lot of code in this question. I'm trying to be as thorough and precise as possible.

I have a `Measurement`class. Many of my models have one or more properties of type `Measurement`. This class maps to the database as a string using a `ValueConverter`. What I would like to do is convert form data, namely strings, to this type upon form submission. So, I created a custom `ModelBinder`.

```cs
     public class MeasurementModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {

        public MeasurementModelBinder() { }

        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if(bindingContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext)); }

            ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if(valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None) { throw new Exception(); }

            string valueString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString)) { throw new Exception(); }

            Measurement result = new Measurement(valueString);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

I would like this `MeasurementModelBinder` to apply to all properties of this type in every model. So I'm trying to do that. Here's an example of a model that has `Measurement` type properties.

```cs
    public class Material
    {
        [Key]
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Measurement Density { get; set; }
        public Measurement Conductivity { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Specific Heat")]
        public Measurement SpecificHeat { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

        public Material() { }

        public Material(string name, Measurement density, Measurement conductivity, Measurement specificHeat, string description = "")
        {
            Name = name;
            Density = density;
            Description = description;
            Conductivity = conductivity;
            SpecificHeat = specificHeat;
        }

        public override string ToString() { return Name; }
    }
```

As for the controller, I'm just using a test controller right now, a modified version of one of Visual Studio's auto-generated MVC Entity Framework controller with views. Here's one of the actions in the controller.

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Material material)
        {
            material.Created = DateTime.Now;
            material.Updated = DateTime.Now;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(material);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(material);
        }
```

The `Created` and `Updated` fields are not provided by the form, so I fill them in myself. However, everything else is filled in by the form, as strings. You can see how a `Measurement` object is constructed in the custom model binder class up above.

I have created a `ModelBinderProvider` class, seen below.

```cs
    public class MeasurementModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if(context == null) { throw new ArgumentException(nameof(context)); }

            if(!context.Metadata.IsComplexType && context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Measurement))
            {
                return new MeasurementModelBinder();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

And I have registered the provider in the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method, like this.

```cs
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MeasurementModelBinderProvider());
    });
```

This is the form that is being submitted.

```html
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Density" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Density" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Density" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Conductivity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Conductivity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Conductivity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SpecificHeat" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SpecificHeat" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SpecificHeat" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

I would like the submission of this form to add a new record to the material table with all fields filled in. It doesn't do that. Instead, it adds a new record where all the `Measurement` properties are null.

I have tried adding the `[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MeasurementModelBinder))]` attribute to the `Measurement` class and that did not help. In fact, it caused an "Unable to resolve service" error, and when I got rid of that error by adding `services.AddScoped<IModelBinder, MeasurementModelBinder>();` to `ConfigureServices()`, I still got the same result from my action.

I have also tried adding the `[BindProperty(BinderType typeof(MeasurementModelBinder))]` attribute to the properties in the model themselves, and it doesn't help. Furthermore, that is something I would rather not do. Is there any way to just make it work on all `Measurement` type properties? If not, is there any way to just make it work at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and when I add the `[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MeasurementModelBinder))]` attribute to the `Measurable` class, it worked for me. I think you should add the `[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MeasurementModelBinder))]` attribute to the `Measurement` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your Measurement class is a ComplexType, so the Model Binder fails to get registered, due to *!context.Metadata.IsComplexType*

Suggested Fix:

```
public class MeasurementModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if(context == null) { throw new ArgumentException(nameof(context)); }

        if(context.Metadata.IsComplexType && context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Measurement))
        {
            return new MeasurementModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```